# Receiving incomplete UDP packet

Tags: c, sockets, networking, udp

We are talking about **UDP packets**, since a packet is sent we only receive it, if it is all complete.

I have this **udp writing** function

```
int udp_write(int socket, const char *buffer, struct sockaddr_in *si_out){
    socklen_t len = sizeof(*si_out);
    if (sendto(socket, buffer, strlen(buffer)+1, 0, (struct sockaddr *)si_out, len) < 0){
        critical_error_udp("error sending datagram");
        return -1;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

And this is my **udp listening** function

```
char * udp_listening(int socket, char *buffer, struct sockaddr_in *si_in){
    socklen_t len = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    long recv_len;
    if((recv_len = recvfrom(socket, buffer, BUF_SIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr *)si_in, (socklen_t *)&len)) < 0) {
      critical_error_udp("error recvfrom");
    }
    return buffer;
}
```

I'm sending from the server the string `HELLO_INPUT_CREDENTIALS`, which is successfully sent.

packet sniffing using wireshark:

[image: packet sniffing using wireshark:]

When im sending the string to the client, client receives `HELLO_INPUT_CRED\x02`. I don't get why im getting `\x02` (Start of text ASCII value) instead the remaining string.

server sending string:

[image: server sending string]

client receiving string:

[image: client receiving string]

**Update**:
I've added the client code and edited my udp_listening function (thanks to Craig)

This is the client code:

```
int hello_server(struct sc_messages *all, int main_socket, struct sockaddr_in *server){
    struct sc_messages * hi_message = get_sc_message_byid(all,1);
    if(udp_write(main_socket, hi_message->request, server) < 0){
        error_console_log("sending hello");
        return -1;
    }
    char echo_buffer[BUF_SIZE];
    memset(echo_buffer, 0, sizeof(echo_buffer));
    char *reply = udp_listening(main_socket, echo_buffer, server);
    if(strcmp(reply, hi_message->reply) == 0){
        return 1;
    }else{
        error_console_log("recieving hello");
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Both apps have the same `sc_messages` structure.

[image]

Comment: They're called "packets" or "datagrams", not "packages".

Comment: BUF_SIZE = 1024

Comment: We need to see the code that invokes your `udp_*` functions. Please _edit_ your question and add this as additional code blocks at the bottom. At a glance, you're passing down to `udp_listening` a parameter of `char *buffer`. But, you read into `char buf[BUF_SIZE]`. Then, you `malloc` a _new_ `buffer`, copy from `buf` to `buffer` and `return` it. So, why pass a value as an arg only to have it ignored? Does the caller of `udp_listening` use the _returned_ value or does it expect that the buffer it passed to get filled in?

Comment: Also, there is no need to nul-terminate `buf`, or even use `strlen()`, since the complete datagram length is in `recv_len` and the sender includes a null terminator in the datagram's payload (which is redundant to do in UDP, BTW): `buffer = malloc(recv_len); memcpy(buffer, buf, recv_len);`

Comment: I've edited the question. Added code and edited the udp_listening function. Thanks

Comment: I suggest the value of `BUFSIZE` is really 16, the length of `HELLO_INPUT_CRED`. It shouldn't be a manifest constant: it should be an input parameter to your `udp_listening()` function, supplied by the caller along with `buffer` itself.

Comment: Your updated code is pretty different from the original, but still needs a [mcve], not just a few functions.

Comment: @user207421 You can tell in the debugger screenshot that it's 1024 as claimed.

Comment: @Shawn No I can't. You would have to prove that `hello_server()` and `udp_listening()` were both in the same compilation unit, or that they both saw the same value for `BUF_SIZE`. *Clearly* it is 16 in `udp_listening()`. No other explanation. That's why I suggested making it a parameter, to eliminate different definitions of `BUF_SIZE` as a source of error. Poor API design here.

Comment: @user207421 Look at the screenshot after *client receiving string:* (which is from an older version of `udp_listening()` ; see edit history). It's 1024 there too. And if it was 16, `recv_len` couldn't be 18...

Comment: @Shawn So `BUF_SIZE` is 18. The receive buffer is 1024 because that's what the calling method passed in, but it didn't provide `BUF_SIZE`. It's the only explanation. If the received length was a lot larger you would consider whether the socket receive buffer is < 1024, but it can't be as low as 18.

Comment: @user207421 Again, if you look at the screenshots and the (original) functions, you'll see `BUF_SiZE` has to be 1024 in both. OP does need to provide actual complete example programs that reproduce the issue, but I'm 99% confident that not having space to read a 24 byte packet isn't the problem.

Comment: @Shawn The screenshots don't provide that information. They provide the information that `buffer` is `char[1024]` as passed into the function. They don't provide the value of `BUF_SIZE` *in* the function anywhere. If you think otherwise please state why. `BUF_SIZE` must be 18 at the pont it is passed into `recvfrom()`. That would explain the problem, and nothing else would. Again if you think otherwise please state why. Mere unsupported assertion is not sufficient at this stage of the discussion, and neither is your confidence factor.

Comment: I give up. If you don't understand the variable information shown, I'm not going to explain further.

Comment: @Shawn You've explained nothing. You've just asserted. The 'variable information shown' does not include `BUF_SIZE`, which is not a variable.

Comment: Just to do a test, replace BUF_SIZE recv_from by the hardcoded value 32 (Large enough to receive the string you show). Be prepared to have a crash if the buffer is actually smaller than that!

Comment: @user207421 - Even `BUF_SIZE` 18 wouldn't lead to `\x02` `\0` instead of `E` `N`.

Comment: @Armali Agreed. That's why I thought it must be 16, with the rest being leftover junk. Evidently this isn't the real code.

Comment: Packets are layer-3, e.g. IP, datagrams. UDP uses datagrams, which is the "D" in UDP (User Datagram Protocol).

Comment: The debugger screenshot mentions `buf`, which doesn't even exist in the code you posted. So that debugger is for different code.

Comment: Use `strace` to see the arguments that are passed to `recvfrom()`, then you'll see what's being passed as the 3rd argument.